# Does Blender Have an equivalent to Xview in 3Ds Max?

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv, vertices, sculpting

In Max, it was relatively easy to detect mesh errors. You could simply go to the viewport settings and click on the Xview button and see several options that would highlight all kinds of errors, such as overlapping vertices and face orientation, etc.

Is there an equivalent to that in Blender? I haven't been able to find one, probably due to some terminology being a slightly different from 3Ds Max to Blender.

I'm not planning on 3D Printing, this is for a game-ready asset.

Answer (score 4):

There's an addon called *Mesh: 3D-Print Toolbox* that gathers several tools of Blender in order to check your mesh. Enable the addon, select the object, open the *N panel > 3D-Print* then click on the *Check All* button. Under *Result* you'll see the errors, click on the one you want in order to hightlight it in your mesh. You can also click on the *Make Manifold* button to fix some issues:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a paid addon called *Mech Check GPU Edition* that can display in viewport  n-gons, E and N poles, isolated vertices, non-manifold edges, and so on. Except it doesn't have UV-related functionality like in 3Ds Max.